# Create dynamic classes / objects to be included in a list

Tags: java, design-patterns

I have a xlsx file, that has some tabs with different data. I want to be able to save each row of a tab in a list. The first thing that comes to mind is a list of lists, but I was wondering if there is another way. I'd like to save that information in a object, with all its benefits, but can't think of a way to generate/create such diverse objects on the fly. The data in the xlsx is diverse and ideally the program is agnostic of any content.

So instead of e.g. create a list for each row, than put that list in another list for each tab and each tab in another list, I'd like to store the information that each row represents in a single object and just have a list of different objects.

A small graphic to visualize the problem :

```
+--------------------------------------------------------------------+
|LIST                                                                |
|                                                                    |
|    +------------------+ +------------------+ +-----------------+   |
|    | Class1           | | Class2           | | Class3          |   |
|    |------------------| |------------------| |-----------------|   |
|    | var1             | | var1             | | var5            |   |
|    | var2             | | var2             | | var6            |   |
|... | var3             | |                  | | var7            |...|
|    |                  | |                  | |                 |   |
|    |                  | |                  | |                 |   |
|    |                  | |                  | |                 |   |
|    |                  | |                  | |                 |   |
|    +------------------+ +------------------+ +-----------------+   |
|                                                                    |
+--------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: How many tabs are we talking about? How about creating a separate list for each tab?

Comment: That would not solve my problem. If I have a list for each tab, I still would need either a list of lists or some kind of objects to hold the data. Which brings me back to my question. :)

Comment: So you need the data in one place / object?

Comment: Yes, instead of e.g. create a list for each row and than put that lists in another list for each tab, I'd like to store the information that each row represents in a single object. I also updated my question to clarify this !

Comment: And what kind of data are we talking about? Would a string representation of each cell be sufficient or do you need to be able to use the data (as an integer for example)?

Comment: How about a generic class `Row` which will contain all the information in a row from your file.  Then you simply create a list of `Row`s.

Comment: @Octoshape Strings would be fine, although I'd like to be able to save integers,too.

Comment: Do you need sample code? I like Trenins idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about a generic class `Row` which will contain all the information in a row from your file.  Then you simply create a list of `Row`s.  Methods for the `Row` can allow you to get each column.

Without knowing more about the data, you will not be able to write classes to encapsulate it.  You could "dynamically" create classes to create new source code.  But then the question is, how would you use the new classes?

Comment: I want to be agnostic about the row schema. So that for example one row can have 3 'variables' and another 16. The only thing that came to mind was an object that just contains a list. But that is just another list in lists solution - which I want to avoid.

Comment: Lets say you had a list of classes, each class is created specific to the row.  How would you use this list?  It would be a list of `Object` or a list of some common base class or interface right?  This base class or interface would then have to have generic methods for getting the columns.  Well, this is what `Row` is doing. You can define a method `Row.getColumn(int index)` which will get you the `index`th column of the row.  Internally, `Row` would store the columns in a list.  You would then keep track of a list of `Row`s.

Answer (score 1):

Well since you want to avoid a "list of lists" kind of solution there would be another way.

This might not be very efficient or fast but I don't have any experience with it, so maybe it isn't too bad. Here's the idea:

For each Row:

Use javassist to create as many fields as needed dynamically that contain each cell's information. Then create an instance of this class and store it in your list of rows. You could also add a field with information about this particular row (e.g. how many fields there are or their names or types or whatever you might need).

The number of fields or methods could also be determined using Reflection.

To get started with javassist there's a tutorial [here](http://www.csg.ci.i.u-tokyo.ac.jp/~chiba/javassist/tutorial/tutorial2.html#add/).

---

Besides that I don't think there's much to do that does **not** involve some sort of `List<List<SomeType>>`

Comment: So how would one access each variable?  Would it be named something like `variable5` for the 5th column?  If so, I don't see how this is any better than a list of lists. (no offense to you Octoshape - you are trying to meet OP's requirements and this is a really great solution.  But I don't see how to get any better than a list of lists with generic data)

Comment: To access the variables you could use Reflection. `Class.getFields()`

Comment: @Trenin none taken. :)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but it's not exactly what I had in mind. Nonetheless a good post !

Comment: I had nothing particular in mind, just wanted some advice, since the list of lists approach seemed somehow to abstract for me, but I will use a variant of Trenin's approach. Thanks again for your answer.